# Насколько приемлемо перечисление (enum) в POJO классе для базы данных

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Мне очень смущает вопрос про внутренние классы, перечисления в POJO объекте.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    private Role role;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    
    public static enum Role {
        ENGINEER, MARKETER
    }
}
```

- Будет ли лишнюю память занимать каждый такой POJO объект (экземпляр)
  в базе данных или вообще?
- Скажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать эту    «схему ролей»: в
  отдельном классе или оставить как есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я знаю:

1. enum всегда статика, поэтому static можно убрать.
2. enum это Singletone на уровне самой JVM.

Соответственно лишнюю память такой подход занимать не будет.

Как видно роли имеются в виду только работники с ролями... Поэтому в таком подходе все норм, но может меня кто-то поправит.

Если у Вас еще будет класс в котором используются такое же перечисление - имеет смысл вынести enum отдельно.